# How can you find the distance between two skew planes?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I understand that there is a unique line perpendicular to both planes and the length of that line is the distance between the planes but how would I go about finding the what the equation of that line is?

Comment: Are you talking about 2 dimensional planes in 3 dimensions?  Parallel planes?

Comment: I'm talking about plants in the 4th dimension. In 4 dimensions a plane will be parameterized by exactly two parameters and
will have exactly 4 components consisting of linear or affine functions of the 2 parameters. I do not know how to use this information to come up with a method.

Comment: Could you set up the distance (squared) between two points (one from each plane) as a function of your parameterizations and set all partial derivatives to zero?  Or is that too computationally difficult?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it the same way as two lines in 3D.

Parameterize your planes by base points $p_0, p_1$ and pairs of vectors $v_0^0, v_0^1, v_1^0, v_1^1.$

You want to find the four parameters $\alpha_i^j$ so that the vector $(p_0 + \alpha_0^0 v_0^0 + \alpha_0^1 v_0^1)-(p_1 + \alpha_1^0v_1^0+\alpha_1^1v_1^1)$ is perpendicular to both planes. This leads to a linear system of four equations in four unknowns
$$[(p_0 + \alpha_0^0 v_0^0 + \alpha_0^1 v_0^1)-(p_1 + \alpha_1^0v_1^0+\alpha_1^1v_1^1)] \cdot v_i^j = 0$$

Comment: So you would solve the four equations to get the four unknowns and the four value found would correspond the four different dimension (say w,x,y,z). Then put those points in the distance formula so get the distance?

Comment: Once you have the four numbers plug them into $(p_0 + \alpha_0^0 v_0^0 + \alpha_0^1 v_0^1)$ and $(p_1 + \alpha_1^0v_1^0+\alpha_1^1v_1^1)$ to get the pair of closest points.

Comment: okay thank you so much!